# Extract String value from Node

Tags: swift3, vapor

I'm trying to query a database using something like this:

```
let db = drop.database?.driver as? MySQLDriver
let query = "select \(fields) from \(table) where \(condition)"
let result = try db.raw(query)
```

I get the following Node object as result:

```
array([Node.Node.object(["field_name": Node.Node.string("value_info")])])
```

How can I get the `value_info` into a String variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PathIndexable` to step into the result object, then `Polymorphic` to cast it as a string.

Should look something like this:

```
let valueInfo = result[0, "field_name"]?.string
```

Comment: Can't do it. `value_info` is the result of a query. Let's say, if my query is something like `select "test" as field_name from dual`, I get `array([Node.Node.object(["field_name": Node.Node.string("test")])])`. So, your solution can't be used.

Comment: Instead, `let valueInfo = result[0, "field_name"]?.string` works.